# 'git add .' doesn't work

Tags: git, repository, git-add

I am currently trying to setup Git for a project I have been working on for a while. I do remember quite a while ago setting up Git but never used it for various reasons. Now I want to use it i am getting a strange issue that I believe is related to an old install.

To start a fresh I installed a fresh Ubuntu OS so that there would be no Git install present and I copied the project (Grails) over. I then navigated to the directory and run the following commands:

```
git init

git remote add origin https://USERNAME@bitbucket.org/USERNAME/APPNAME.git
```

Then I ran:

```
git add .
```

This is where i get the error below:

```
fatal: Not a git repository: /home/user/workspace/App_V3/.git/modules/plugins/grails-spring-security-ui
```

This error is weird as this doesn't even match the directory I am in as the directory is below:

**/home/user/Workspace/App_V7/**

I am thinking that originally I may have setup the Git in the App_V3 folder on the old OS but don't know why it still points to that directory as I have run the code below to re-initialize it:

```
rm -rf .git
git init
```

Can someone please help me with this as its really frustrating :S

Thanks in advance

Comment: when you say you copied the project over, was it already under git version control or not? You can get rid of the `.git` folder, if present, before running git init

Comment: What do you mean by version control? I installed GIT ages ago in another folder and then this project was copied into a new folder. As shown above I have run "rm rf .git" and then git init again however still get same issue. I do this this is a problem with the directory structure as this is a fresh OS.

Comment: even though `.git` in current working directory is deleted, git will continue to look for it in a few other places before giving up. And in case if does find a `.git` elsewhere it will attempt to work with it. Check out this **[answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6269740/319204)** for a list of places to check for and delete the stale `.git`s on your filesystem.

Comment: What’s the output when you run `git rev-parse --git-dir` in `App_V7`?
`

Comment: What happens when you run the following command `git status` Also look for the folder `.git` as where that folder is represents the root of your new Git repo

Comment: I have deleted the .git folder in the root using "rm -rf .git" and then ran the command "git rev-parse --git-dir" and the output was: fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount parent /media)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).

Comment: Is there anyone who can assit as I am still getting issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I moved all of the files one at a time to a new folder and then seemed to work fine :)

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 18):

### Moving repositories with submodules is problematic

> I am thinking that originally I may have setup the Git in the App_V3 folder on the old OS

This is the source of the problem.

What matters is the version of git when the repository (or more specifically, the referenced submodule) was originally created.

Consider a repository with one submodule in `vendor/awesome`, how git behaved when creating the submodule is quite different.

### git version < 1.7.8

The contents of `vendor/awesome/.git` is a folder - just like any git checkout so for example the folder structure of a checkout would be:

```
.gitmodules
.git
    ...
vendor/
    awesome
        .git
            config
            HEAD
            index
            packed-refs
            ...
```

There's no problem moving this kind of repository around, as there are no paths stored anywhere.

### git version 1.7.8 or 1.7.9

[1.7.8 moved the location of a submodule's .git folder](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.7.8.txt)

> When populating a new submodule directory with "git submodule init",
>   the $GIT_DIR metainformation directory for submodules is created inside
>   $GIT_DIR/modules// directory of the superproject and referenced
>   via the gitfile mechanism. This is to make it possible to switch
>   between commits in the superproject that has and does not have the
>   submodule in the tree without re-cloning.

Therefore `vendor/awesome/.git` is not a folder, it is a file with the following contents:

```
gitdir: /absolute/path/to/main/repo/.git/modules/vendor/awesome
```

And the overal folder structure is:

```
.gitmodules
.git
    ...
    modules
        vendor
            awesome
                config
                HEAD
                index
                packed-refs
                ...

vendor/
    awesome
        .git <- a file
```

The contents of `.git/modules/vendor/awesome/config` specifies where the working tree is:

```
[core]
   ...
   worktree = /absolute/path/to/main/repo/vendor/awesome
```

This was a pretty awesome change - however it introduced a problem, as absolute paths were used to reference locations.

### git version >= 1.7.10

In [version 1.7.10](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.7.10.txt) the use of absolute paths in submodules was modified

> The whole directory that houses a top-level superproject managed by
>   "git submodule" can be moved to another place.

Now `vendor/awesome/.git` if generated with this or a later version of git would contain:

```
gitdir: ../../.git/modules/vendor/awesome
```

The contents of `.git/modules/vendor/awesome/config` specifies where the working tree is:

```
[core]
   ...
   worktree = ../../../../vendor/awesome
```

Once again, there's no problem moving this kind of repository around, as paths a relative to the main repository.

### Moving repositories

With an old, or a new version of git - you're good.

If you're unfortunate enough to work on a repository created in 1.7.8 or 1.7.9 (which from the evidence in the question seems to be the case) *and* move the repository - there are [2 solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10667194/761202):

1. Clone again
2. Correct paths in submodule .git files, and the corresponding worktree config setting

Comment: I have git version  2.8, but my submodules where in version 1.7 format : / Is there someway to automatically migrate to the new format?

Comment: Probably by reading the answer, though you don't _need_ to migrate to the new format.

Comment: the thing is I copied the repository to another dir, and, since it isn't 'migrated' to the new format, submodules failed and I had to update them manually. really cumbersome and not-for-all. so id like to know if tere is an easy way to 'migrate' to new format so I can fwd it to my team...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
git init
git remote add origin https://USERNAME@bitbucket.org/USERNAME/APPNAME.git
```

you should use

```
git clone origin https://USERNAME@bitbucket.org/USERNAME/APPNAME.git .
```

since you want to [clone](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clone.html) an existing repository and not re-create it.