# Git command to move admin (.git) directory to different location

Tags: git

Usually, the `.git` directory resides inside the working tree of a non-bare repository, but there also might be `.git` **file** instead with an `gitdir: <path>` entry pointing to the admin-directory.

Is there a Git command that can move the directory around converting from `.git` directory to `.git` file or visa versa?

Comment: you should be able to just copy/move it yourself and create the file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git - Moving the .git directory to another drive, keep the source code where it is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17913550/git-moving-the-git-directory-to-another-drive-keep-the-source-code-where-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a Git command that can move the directory around converting from `.git` directory to `.git` file or visa versa?

[`git init`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init) does that when the argument [`--separate-git-dir`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init#git-init---separate-git-dirltgitdirgt) is present in the command line. The documentation explains:

> **--separate-git-dir=<git dir>**
>
> Instead of initializing the repository as a directory to either `$GIT_DIR` or `./.git/`, create a text file there containing the path to the actual repository. This file acts as filesystem-agnostic Git symbolic link to the repository.
>
> If this is reinitialization, the repository will be moved to the specified path.

Comment: `git clone` has the same option.

Comment: @axiac: could you please add your answer to the other questions? Then this could be deleted.