# I accidentally initially set up git development to C:

Tags: blender

I accidentally initially set up git development to **C:**

how to I move it to `C:\BlenderDEV`?

http://www.pasteall.org/pic/show.php?id=81683 - this is my problem

upon initial install my dev directory was C:, so it was checking over 5000 files for changes.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19097259/how-to-move-a-git-repository-into-another-directory-and-make-that-directory-a-gi

Comment: Is BlenderDEV a Git repository, or is it something else?

Comment: You are asking how to move a directory?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: The poster should then ask that question; there's no reason to assume one way or the other. The poster should more clearly state the question, and asking for clarification is precisely the correct thing to do here.

Comment: @KenWhite: Certainly, clarification is needed. Yet, there is no reason to scare off new users by assuming the single most trivial interpretation of the question and then asking for that clarification in a tone that can very well be understood as mocking the OP for their stupidity to ask such a trivial question.

Comment: when I installed Git , I set my initial development (the first screen) to C:\

So when I installed - it asked where I want my Git development folder to be, I walked away, (to help someone at home) and my daughter hit enter, now when I fire up git, it scans every file on my pc....

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: The comment you addressed was a simple, polite question. There was no mocking, insulting tone, or anything else implied, and the poster you addressed is certainly very familiar with this site. I find your public chastising much more objectionable for new users to see than the tone taken in the comment.

Comment: @KenWhite: Please read my comment again. I wrote *can very well be understood*. Where exactly do you read that I accuse the author of the question of creating that impression intentionally? I merely remarked that the question *can* easily be interpreted to carry an insulting message. Also, I did not address any particular poster; as I said in my comment, I was referring to new users, and that includes people who have never posted anything here, but read the question and the comments.

Comment: http://www.pasteall.org/pic/show.php?id=81683

See?

Comment: BluePrintRandom: Please [edit] your question to add the additional information, rather than posting it in the comments where it can get lost in the clutter. It should be in your question where it can be easily seen. Thanks.

Comment: @KenWhite: Sorry, I meant "that I accuse the author of the comment of creating that impression intentionally". I think the question written in the comment can be interpreted as an implicit insult, yet I acknowledge your statement that you do not think so, and instead prefer to see me "lecturing users" in my comment.

Comment: @KenWhite: Anything else on this topic should rather not be discussed here, but [in the respective meta question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-new-users), where a perceived or actual "decline in the level of civility" is discussed in depth.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Once again, there is no need for you to be chastising people here that are considerably more familiar with the site than you, and you're the only one continuing to discuss it here.

Comment: why did I get a -1?

I looked on google for a whole day before posting...

Comment: @KenWhite: I'd kindly like to ask you to stop the aggressivity toward me by constantly accusing me of "chastising people" when I just made a friendly remark in the sense of the [*Could we please be a bit nicer to new users?* meta discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-new-users). I will not continue the discussion here, as meta is the correct place for this.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to right click on C:\BlenderDev and do -> add Git -> all files

after I did

git init c:\BlenderDev

Thanks all,