# How to move a local git repository to the root folder and preserve history?

Tags: git

I have a local git repository which is inside a project. I have decided that some code needs to be in another project but I only want one git repository.

**Current directory structure:**

```
Solution->
 - Project1
   - .git
 - Project2
```

**Desired directory structure:**

```
Solution->
 - .git (tracks both projects)
 - Project1
 - Project2
```

How do I move `.git` to the root folder (`Solution`) so that it can begin to watch both Project1 and Project2 without losing track of the modifications/commits?

**Note**: I don't really care about preserving the history of the files that are going to be moved to the Project2 folder.

**Note**: This is not a duplicate to ([this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19097259/how-to-move-a-git-repository-into-another-directory-and-make-that-directory-a-gi)) because I'm not moving a git repository and its whole contents. I want to only move the git repository to the root folder.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to move a git repository into another directory and make that directory a git repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19097259/how-to-move-a-git-repository-into-another-directory-and-make-that-directory-a-gi)

Comment: @KyleTrauberman I'm not a git expert but if I do what the answer says, wouldn't I lose all the changes made in Project1? (Because of the directory change)

Comment: Move actual files to Solution/Project1/Project1 with git. Manually move .git folder to Solution. Manually move back files to Solution/Project1. Add Project2. Enjoy.

Comment: @iKiWiXz Thanks. That is actually clever. I didn't understand what was going on until I did it myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### The `git add -u` solution

Most elegant, needs 6 commands.

```
cd Solution/
#dot means "move it here"
mv Project1/.git .

#make git add deleted files
git add -u

#make it recognize them as moved
git add Project1/
```

Now `git status` should show "renamed..."

```
git commit -m'moved to a subfolder'
```

Now check for unwanted files and update .gitignore

```
#add the project2:
git add --all
git commit -m'added project2'
```

#### The subfolder solution

1. in `Solution/Project1/` create a subfolder with the same name: `Solution/Project1/Project1/`.
2. **Move** all other contents (except `.git/`, `.gitignore`, `.gitconfig` and new subfolder) of the `Solution/Project1/` to `Solution/Project1/Project1/`
3. `cd Polution/project1`, `git add --all`, `git commit -m'moved to a subfolder`
4. **Move** all contents of `Solution/Project1` to `Solution`. Now project files are back in `Solution/Project1/` and `.git` and git-files are in the `Solution/`
5. `cd Solution/`, `git status`. Watch for unwanted files. Add them to `.gitignore`
6. `git add --all`, `git commit -m'added project2'`

#### The `git mv` solution

```
cd Solution/Project1/
mkdir Project1/

#Now move all your files with git mv
git mv foo.txt Project1/
git mv bar.js Project1/
git mv fizz/ Project1/
....

git commit -m'moved files to a subfolder'
cd ../
```

Now move all files from `Solution/Project1/` to `Solution`. This is probably done with `mv` command, but I don't catch the exact syntax.

```
# this should work now
git status
# fix .gitignore if necessary
git add --all
git commit -m'added project2'
```

Comment: Thanks. This is a detailed version of iKiWiXz's solution.

Comment: Added the third solution )

Answer (score 1):

- Move the content of the project1 to a subfolder of project1
- Commit changes
- Move project2 to the project1 folder
- Commit

Comment: Here's what you have after letz's solution: Project1/Project1 and Project1/Project2. Just rename Project1 so you now have Solution/Project1 and Solution/Project2. Then move Solution so that it's where you wanted it to be.

Comment: Why you can't make Project1 folder of your projects and simply move the the actual project1 inside a folder? and them move project2 ?

Comment: @letz Thanks, I got it now. I believe iKiWiXz's solution is cleaner though.

Comment: Oh, it seem like a lot of people explain the same solution.