# I need git to include the parent directory

Tags: git, github

I have a program divided into 3 packages.  I have set up a local repo in one of the packages and set it up to push to a repo on gitHub.  I have started work on the second package and I realized I haven't initialized it with git. I wanted to use the same gitHub repo to push the second package to but I'm not sure it will work since I have already set up my first package to push to it.   I think I should have done git init on the parent folder of the three packages and then the folder/package structure would have shown up on my gitHub repo.  Is there a simple way to fix this?  Thanks!

Comment: This has a solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30629188/how-to-move-a-local-git-repository-to-the-root-folder-and-preserve-history/30629580#30629580

Comment: And here, somewhat less specific: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19097259/how-to-move-a-git-repository-into-another-directory-and-make-that-directory-a-gi?lq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say your parent directory is named `parent`, and your child directories are named `package1`, `package2`, and `package3`. Let's also assume that `package1` is the directory where you have your git repository. I would just make *another* `package1` directory as a child of the original `package1` directory, and move the contents of the original `package1` directory into it. Then move `package2` and `package3` to be children of the original `package1`. You can the rename the original `package1` to parent. `git add --all .` the whole thing, and you now have a repo with all three directories. The cool thing is that you will not lose the history of all the files you moved; git is smart enough to detect renames/moves.

Comment: Thanks!  That sounds like a simple way to do it.

Comment: I clicked the up arrow.  What else do I need to do?

Answer (score -2):

Assume we have directory structure like this:

```
    A
    |
    B
    |
    .git and other files
```

You should:

```
cd B
mkdir C
ls | grep -v '^C$' | xargs -L 1 -I '{}' git mv -r '{}' C/
ls ../ | grep -v '^B$' | xargs -L 1 -I '{}' mv ../'{}' .
git commit -am 'Change directory structure and include parent dir'
```

Comment: Dumping complex shell commands into an answer without explanation isn't very helpful. Please add some context.