# How to init, add an existing remote, then push a new branch in Git?

Tags: git

My friend and I have a remote branch in Gitlab. For some reason I got the project from my friend by copy-paste (I know that's a bad thing). But let's say I got the code, did some changes, and I want to initialize git in it and then push a new branch in our project. Like:

1. Get the project from my friend
2. Do some changes in the code
3. `git init` in the project folder
4. `git remote add origin https://...`
5. `git fetch`
6. In this step, I want to create a branch, say `foo-branch`. Commit my changes, and push it to `origin foo-branch`, with the background commits of master (or any other branch).

What is the right way to do step 6? I have tried that after step 5, I tried `git reset master` so I can get all the older commits from master branch but it didn't worked.

I can give more information if you need.

**Edit 1:** After step 5, I did `git reset origin/master`. It seems like it's something to move on, `git log` shows all the previous commits. But this time `git status` shows all the files even those in the `.gitignore`. Any ideas how to do this correctly?

Comment: How did you "get" the project from your friend? As a tarball? Does the tarball have a `.git` directory in it?

Comment: Via zipping the whole project

Comment: When you unzip, is there `.git` directory?

Comment: No I delete `.git` directory completely after unzipping, sorry I forgot to mention that. Also I have edited the question.

Comment: so you want all your older commits to a new branch foo

Comment: @Nitintiwari That's right. All the older commits + the new one I'm about to commit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the tarball contains code you want to push into `gitlab`, this is what you should do

1. Clone the repository from gitlab
2. Create a new branch and checkout to it
3. Unzip your zip file into the repository (assuming it doesn't have a `.git` inside it).
4. Do a `git diff` to confirm if the changes are correct.
5. `git add`, `git commit`, and `git push` to the new  branch.

Comment: In step 1 you mean cloning the repo to a completely new folder, and in step 4 you mean copy-paste all the files except `.git` from the zip I got to the new clone I just get, right?

Comment: Your solution is actually similar to one of my answers to a question here, right? https://stackoverflow.com/a/58390283/6402099

Comment: Similar. But wait, are you saying you still have the original tarball? In that case you can just extract the `.git` directory you previously (for some reason) deleted.