# How to move .git folder to another place?

Tags: git

In folder `D:\projects\A` I have the .git folder for A. Is there a way to move it to `D:\gitfolder\A`? I found these similar questions:

- [Can I store the .git folder outside the files I want tracked?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/505467/3416774) but it's about *creating* a new init in a different folder, not *moving* it
- [How to move a git repository into another directory and make that directory a git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19097259/3416774) but it's about moving `D:\projects\A`, not the .git folder inside it

So far I've moved the .git folder already. In `D:\gitfolder\A` `git status` works fine, but I'm not sure if it can add new files created in `D:\projects\A` or not.

If possible I would like to be able to still use git commands in `D:\projects\A` as if the move didn't happen.

Answer (score -1):

In folder `D:\projects\A` create a **file** (not folder) named `.git` with this content:

```
gitdir: D:\gitfolder\A\.git
```

In folder `D:\gitfolder\A\.git` edit the config file with this line under `[core]`:

```
worktree = D:\projects\A
```

You can also do this with this command `git config core.worktree D:\projects\A`.

Note that if your path containing space (e.g. `D:\multiple words\A`), then the texts in the .git or config files should have double slashes (i.e. `D:\\multiple words\\A`). And if you use the command, the path should be in quotes `git config core.worktree "D:\multiple words\A"`.

Comment: The backslashes get interpolated in `.git/config` files (`core.worktree` setting) so that is where you need to double them; this isn't related to the spaces, which need quoting when present in a command line. (I'd be slightly, but not totally, surprised to find that they need doubling in the `.git` file with the `gitdir` line too.) To avoid the double-backslash-problem you can simply use forward slashes, which work fine on Windows and have the benefit of being easier to type, as well as no issues with doubling.