# Version Control System directory after moving files to new folder in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea

Initially, all the project files were in `C:\My_Projects\aifarming` and git was initialized here. Then I created a folder named `Backend` and moved all project files to `Backend`.  Now how do I configure the VCS directory in Intellij?

The image shows Git is configured in the root folder `C:\My_Projects\aifarming`, but I'm working on my project in a subfolder `C:\My_Projects\aifarming\Backend`. VCS for this directory is currently set as `<none>` and does not detect changes made to project files.
[image: img]

I tried searching for the solution to it.

Comment: Hi, please check:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19097259/how-to-move-a-git-repository-into-another-directory-and-make-that-directory-a-gi, idea is not detecting a git folder, so please move it to backend folder and it should work fine.

Comment: I need git to be in root folder though.

Comment: Restarted IntelliJ and it is now detecting changes. Also I think `.idea` folder needs to be in the project working directory, not the root directory. In my case, it should be inside `Backend` folder. If anyone faced the same issues before, hope you will clarify about it!